# Spring Hibernate configuration issue: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration

I am trying to create spring+hibernate application, after added hibernate configurations I am getting  `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` while starting tomcat server:

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml]: Initialization of bean
failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
```

hibernate-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.common">
</context:component-scan> 

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.test.common.model.CompanyTypes</value>
            <value>com.test.common.model.Employee</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
            <!--prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop-->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

jars included:

[image]

please guide, thanks in advance..

Comment: What Spring versions are you using?

Comment: Are you using mix version of different spring modules ? Please download latest spring and use those only ...

Comment: I am spring version 3.2

Comment: There's is something that is not version 3.2. Show us all your libraries.

Comment: please have a look for jar file included

Comment: Yeah, so all the `3.2.1` vs `3.2.3` and one `3.0.7` seems to be causing issues. Synchronize all of those (except `spring-security` which is a package of its own).

Comment: Your spring dispatcher configuration is ok but there may b problem with the jars you have added... Add all the jars with same version for spring..Use "3.2.1" Or "3.2.2" but be specific with release

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i used same jar in another project and it is working fine there.. is there any other problem?

Comment: No, this is the problem. It might not have come up in another project because that project didn't need a conflicting class/method. Don't use different versions of the Spring libraries. All the Spring libraries [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework) that are currently at version 4.0.3.RELEASE should always be at the same version in your projects.